# Why is Raiden's Muramasa able to cut through anything?

Tags: weapon, metal-gear-solid

I know Raiden (from 'Metal Gear Revengeance') has a sword that can cut through anything but I wanted to know what the underlying justification was for this ability?

**What technology allows his blade to cut through anything?**

Comment: Where is this picture from? It looks like a picture from the Raiden vs. Wolverine Death Battle video, which explains what the sword is, and how it works.

Comment: @CBredlow - I just picked one that looked nice. The trailer vid above shows the sword in action...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raiden's weapon was a [**high-frequency blade**](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/High-frequency_blade).

> A high-frequency blade was a sword reinforced by a powerful
>   alternating current and resonated at extremely high frequencies. This
>   oscillation weakened the molecular bonds of anything it cut, thereby
>   increasing its cutting ability. Striking, cutting, and thrusting
>   attacks were performed with the blade, with the sharpened edge and
>   point used for lethal attacks, and the blunt edge used as a clubbing
>   weapon. Proficient users were also able to wield the blade with such
>   accuracy and speed that they were able to deflect bullets.

Basically, it uses sound waves and electricity to cut through things (the latter of which you can see in the picture).

Comment: Thank you, very much, I've been wondering this for a long time, and am trying to create a fictional blade that could cut through anything.

Comment: Feel free to accept if this answers your question (you might need to wait 15 minutes).

Comment: Drat. I was too busy editing the question to answer it :-)

Comment: It also can cut through Adamantium, if the people on youtube are correct.

Comment: No it couldn't. Those people on Youtube are INCORRECT. Different universe, different properties.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing up two separate questions here: Raiden's High-Frequency blade operates as per Jonah's answer, but the Muramasa is Jetstream Sam's blade, not Raiden's:

[image: Muramasa]

Vs.

[image: HF Blade]

This is the Muramasa, and as the final fight demonstrates, it's able to cut through things that Raiden's default HF Blade can't. The reasoning for this is its heritage: according to the wiki:

```
According to Blade Wolf the sword's high-frequency conversion carried over the already 
excellent properties of the original sword, making it extremely powerful.
```

So, if you were asking why the Muramasa was able to cut through anything instead of the standard HF Blade, it's because of <s>magic</s> superior craftsmanship.